# Google Apps Script: how to create user list from single GA account using Google App Script and mail it in CSV once a month

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-sheets-api

I'm struggeling few days already with the following code below gathered from resources found on google developers website.

Mind you my JS skills are limited.

Basically what i'm trying to do is:

1. gather users from specific GA account - succes (result is visible in console, via localhost)
2. import this list into a Google Sheet -unsuccesful
3. mail this list once a month in CSV format -unsuccesful

All above via Google Script App editor.

All relevant API's are turned on (Management API, Advanced Services) and necessary client ID and API key have been created and are active plus all scopes.

Where can I find drag-n-drop resources to aid me to finish the job with little modification.

Also is there a way to not trigger the AUTH in Google Script Editor and always be logged in? I get the mssg "gapi is not defined" when I run portions of the code. When I run it via local server it all works perfectly but not in the Editor and it's very annoying switching back 'n forth between GSE and local machine to test.

Here's the code.

```
 function authenticate() {
    return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
        .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.manage.users"})
        .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
  }
  function loadClient() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey("MY-API-KEY");
    return gapi.client.load("https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/analytics/v3/rest")
        .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
  }
    gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
    gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "MY ID"});
  });

function listAccountUserLinks() {
  var request = gapi.client.analytics.management.accountUserLinks.list({
      'accountId': 'SPECIFIC ACCOUNT'
  });
  request.execute(printAccountUserLinks);
}

function printAccountUserLinks(results) {
  if (results && !results.error) {
    var accountLinks = results.items;
    for (var i = 0, accountUserLink; accountUserLink = accountLinks[i]; i++) {
      var entity = accountUserLink.entity;
      var accountRef = entity.accountRef;
      var userRef = accountUserLink.userRef;
      var permissions = accountUserLink.permissions;
      console.log('User Email: ' + userRef.email);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You talk about GAS but you're using the JS gapi client here, what is your actual set up?

Comment: Hi @RafaGuillermo, pardon my knowledge but is there a difference in both? What I wanna do is run it from solely from GAS. And what do you meanby "...what is your actual setup?" 

Above code example is run from my localhost in browser but does not work in GAS.

Comment: Google Apps Script runs in the cloud, it’s based on JavaScript and has native libraries for interacting with Workspace APIs directly. You can’t use the gapi client in Apps Scipt like this, you need to use either the [`SpreadsheetApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) class or the [Advanced Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced).

Comment: How would a GAS code look like especially regarding Oauth authorization? I will look into link you shared. Thx for explaining the difference.

Comment: You don’t need to worry about setting up your project or client ID in Apps Script as it’s all native and it’s handled for you. A consent screen is shown to the user based on the methods you use in your script, else you can define your own. It’s late for me now (22:17) so I’ll post a full example for you tomorrow.

Comment: Thx @RafaGuillermo looking forward to it to get a better understanding.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo did you manage to create the example?

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*You can't use the gapi client in Google Apps Script. You need to use either [built-in Apps Script services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services), [Advanced services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced), or to make the HTTP requests directly and parse the responses using [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app).*

#### More Information:

In order to interact with the Sheets API, you can either use the Google Advanced Spreadsheet service, available for activation under `Services + > Google Sheets API`, or the in-built `SpreadsheetApp` class.

The [Analytics Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference) does not have an Advanced service nor an in-built class so you will need to make HTTP requests for this.

#### Example:

I suggest that when interacting with Sheets, to use the Advanced Spreadsheet service, as it is faster to use than [`SpreadsheetApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app).

Firstly, to get the information from the Analytics Management API, you will need to build your request with the correct authentication. From your comment in your question:

> All relevant API's are turned on (Management API, Advanced Services) and necessary client ID and API key have been created and are active plus all scopes.

I wlll assume that the correct setup in the [Google Cloud Console](http://console.cloud.google.com/) has been completed and the project has been linked to your Apps Script project, so I will skip these steps in my answer.

Firstly you'll need to get the response about the user account links from the Management API using HTTP requests:

```js
// Assuming you got the account ID from elsewhere:
function getUserLinks(accountId) {
  var url = `https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/${accountId}/entityUserLinks`

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
  var options = {
    "headers": {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token,
    },
    "method": "GET",
  }

  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText()
}
```

Then you can print as you like just by passing to your print function:

```js
printAccountUserLinks(getUserLinks("SPECIFIC ACCOUNT"))
```

To make a Sheets API request you can use the Advanced Spreadsheet Service:

```
function importToSheet(spreadsheetId, range, results) {
  // basic request, change as required:
  var request = {
    "range": range, // for example "A1:B1"
    "values": [
      [
        "User Email"
      ],
      [
        results["items"][0]["entity"]["accountRef"]["userRef"]["email"]
      ]
    ],
    "majorDimension": "COLUMNS"
  }

  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.append(request, spreadsheetId, range, {    "valueInputOption": "USER_ENTERED"
  })
}
```

See the full documentation on the Sheets API values update request [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update).

Finally you can export your spreadsheet as a CSV file and attach it to an email for inporting. Here, you can simply use the built-in [`GmailApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app) class:

```js
// spreadsheetId is the ID of the spreadsheet to convert to CSV
function sendCsv(spreadsheetId) {
  var to = "username@domain.com"
  var subject = "Converted CSV"
  var body = "The converted CSV is attached, please take a look"

  GmailApp.sendEmail(to, subject, body, {
    attachments: [{
      fileName: SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getName(),
      content: convertToCSV(spreadsheetId).getBlob().getBytes(),
      mimeType: "text/csv"
    }]
  })
}

function convertToCSV(spreadsheetId) {
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()

  var options = {
    "headers": {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token,
    },
    "method": "GET",
  }
  var params = "export?gid=0&format=csv"
  var url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${spreadsheetId}/${params}`

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)
  return response
}
```

#### Don't forget:

As you're using a GCP project you'll have to [set explicit scopes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes) for your script in the manifest. The scopes you will need are:

```json
...
"oauthScopes": [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.manage.users",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
  "https://mail.google.com/"
],
...
```

#### References:

- [Built-in Google Services | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services)
- [Advanced services | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [UrlFetchApp | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)
- [API Reference | Analytics Management API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference)
- [Home - Google Cloud Platform](http://console.cloud.google.com/)
- [Class SpreadsheetApp | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [Class GmailApp | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app)
- [Authorization Scopes - Setting explicit scopes | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes)